# cannot read property 'idCounter' of undefined hostcontainerinfo

Tags: reactjs

Got this error in a reactjs component following some refactoring. Couldn't find any direct information on it. See below for the code that caused the problem and the fix.

This is the full exception:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_idCounter' of undefined
at ReactDOMTextComponent.mountComponent (ReactDOMTextComponent.js:78)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at ReactKonvaComponent.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
at ReactKonvaComponent.mountAndInjectChildren (react-konva.js:97)
at ReactKonvaComponent.mountComponent (react-konva.js:311)
at Object.mountComponent (ReactReconciler.js:45)
at Object.mountChildren (ReactMultiChild.js:236)
at Object.mountAndInjectChildren (react-konva.js:97)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
at Object.componentDidMount (react-konva.js:248)
at Object.chainedFunction [as componentDidMount] (factory.js:617)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:264
at measureLifeCyclePerf (ReactCompositeComponent.js:75)
at ReactCompositeComponent.js:263
at CallbackQueue.notifyAll (CallbackQueue.js:76)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.close (ReactReconcileTransaction.js:80)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.closeAll (Transaction.js:209)
at ReactReconcileTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:156)
at batchedMountComponentIntoNode (ReactMount.js:126)
at ReactDefaultBatchingStrategyTransaction.perform (Transaction.js:143)
at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactDefaultBatchingStrategy.js:62)
at Object.batchedUpdates (ReactUpdates.js:97)
at Object._renderNewRootComponent (ReactMount.js:319)
at Object._renderSubtreeIntoContainer (ReactMount.js:401)
at Object.render (ReactMount.js:422)
at Object../src/index.js (index.js:16)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7268e22d223498460ebe:659)
at fn (bootstrap 7268e22d223498460ebe:85)
at Object.2 (konva jsdom:1)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 7268e22d223498460ebe:659)
at ./node_modules/ansi-regex/index.js.module.exports (bootstrap 7268e22d223498460ebe:708)
at bundle.js:712
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i had two tag closings on the same element. Bad copy and paste.

```
<Drawing scale={scale}
         x={this.state.x}
         y={this.state.y}
         w={this.state.w}/>    <=== Needed to remove extra />
         h={this.state.h}/>
```